# How can you merge two tables without losing any of the rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I'm trying to merge two tables. A `student` table and a `department` table, but I don't want to lose any of the departments that don't have students. When I use `NATURAL JOIN` I lose them because the primary key is `DEPT_ID` and some of the departments don't have students so they don't show up in the merged table. I tried too look up other way to merge tables I haven't had any luck so far.

My Attempt:

```
SELECT DEPT_NAME, 
COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) AS NumberOfStudentsInDepartment
FROM Students RIGHT JOIN Departments
GROUP BY DEPT_NAME
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 ASC;
```

Comment: "Left Join" perhaps? Unless I misunderstand the "merge" you mean. It would help if you provided some code.

Comment: If you are using `natural join`, then you are not using SQL Server.  I removed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Right Join

```
Select * from Students S RIGHT JOIN Department D on D.Dept_Id = S.Dept_id
```

Or Left Join

```
Select * from Department D LEFT JOIN Students S on D.Dept_Id = S.Dept_id
```

[**Learn more about how joins work here**](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/database/visual_sql_joins.aspx)

Comment: So quick follow up question. I'm trying to find the total number of students in each department. When I was using normal `NATURAL JOIN` it worked fine. However, with `RIGHT JOIN` I get an error. Do you know why that would break it? My query is in the question.

Comment: GROUP BY DEPT_NAME
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @NatashaAlexandrov you are running it on oracle db? But I gave answer for mysql

Comment: I'm in one of those online coding environments (e.g. HackerRank, HackerEart). I just realized that it was set to Oracle. When I changed it to MySQL it says this: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1:  [stuff about manual] 'GROUP BY DEPT_NAME ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 ASC' at line 4`

Comment: @NatashaAlexandrov use `GROUP BY D.DEPT_NAME`